# Assign Users to Project List In Asp.net Mvc 5 Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to Assign Users to My Project But there is problem when i run it i get error

Multiple object sets per type are not supported. The object sets 'ApplicationUsers' and 'Users' can both contain instances of type 'ProjectManagementSystem.Models.ApplicationUser'.
This is in my IdentityModels.cs

```
public class ApplicationUser
    : IdentityUser<string, ApplicationUserLogin,
    ApplicationUserRole, ApplicationUserClaim>
{
    public ApplicationUser()
    {
        this.Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

    }


    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity>
        GenerateUserIdentityAsync(ApplicationUserManager manager)
    {
        var userIdentity = await manager
            .CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        return userIdentity;
    }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string User_name { get; set; }

    public string City { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Project> Projects { get; set; }
}
```

This is also from IdentityModels.cs

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Project>()
         .HasMany<ApplicationUser>(c => c.UsersOnProjects).WithMany(i => i.Projects)
         .Map(t => t.MapLeftKey("ProjectID")
             .MapRightKey("Id")
             .ToTable("Projects"));
```

And this to:

```
    public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<ProjectManagementSystem.Models.Clients> Clients { get; set; }

    public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<ProjectManagementSystem.Models.ProjectCategory> 
                                            ProjectCategories { get; set; }

    public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<ProjectManagementSystem.Models.Project> Projects
                                                              { get; set; }

    public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<ProjectManagementSystem.Models.ApplicationUser> 
                                                       ApplicationUsers { get; set; }
```

Now this is my Project Model

```
  public class Project
  {
    [Key]
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Project Name")]
    public string ProjectTitle { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public string Url { get; set; }

    public int ProjectCategoryId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Project Category")]
    public virtual ProjectCategory ProjectCategory { get; set; }

    public int ClientId { get; set; }

    public virtual Clients Client { get; set; }

    public string Budget { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Start Date")]
    public string StartDate { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "End Date")]
    public string EndDate { get; set; }

    public string UserId { get; set; }

    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUser> UsersOnProjects { get; set; }
 }
```

I tried everything like removing this part

```
 public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<ProjectManagementSystem.Models.ApplicationUser> 
                                               ApplicationUsers { get; set; }
```

Changing my ProjectController

```
  ViewBag.UserId = new SelectList(db.ApplicationUsers, "Id", "Name");

  To

 ViewBag.UserId = new SelectList(db.Users, "Id", "Name");
```

And much more but I always get same error....
I have created user roles and groups from this link
http://typecastexception.com/post/2014/08/10/ASPNET-Identity-20-Implementing-Group-Based-Permissions-Management.aspx

Maybe there is something with this that giving me error.
I'm creating my controller using entityframwork

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: Are you using a separate custom DB context or extending the in built identity context?

Comment: I don't use separate db context I have extended builtin identity context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solve it by putting this line in my View

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(false)
```

And putting var modelStateErrors and break point on if (ModelState.IsValid)

```
var modelStateErrors = this.ModelState.Values.SelectMany(m => m.Errors);
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Projects.Add(project);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

After that I found out that I have error message in my project model and that ProjectCategory was Required. I removed that and now it does work....

```
public int ProjectCategoryId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Project Category")]
    public virtual ProjectCategory ProjectCategory { get; set; }
```